# How to scale and rot90 a 3D Array faster (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I want to scale and then rotate (by 90 deg) a 3D array in a faster way. I have this code:

```
Array3            = rand(4,3,20) ;
scaled_Array3     = 1 - 1 ./(1 + exp(Array3 ));
rot_scaled_Array3 = rot90(scaled_Array3);
```

is there maybe a better or cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the bottleneck in your algorithm is a `flip` and a `permute` operation (look at how `rot90` is implemented)? If so, I don't think there's much one can do using MATLAB functions. If not, better `profile` the code and look for other (likely much more significant) bottlenecks.

Comment: I already used profile and the result was that the rot90 function is too slow.

Comment: The *profiler* may tell you that `rot90` is consuming the most time but this is good as it indicates that a MATLAB-native function (which usually is fast) seems to be the bottleneck. Now have a look at your code and see if you a) really need to call `rot90` so often (I assume that you call it thousands of times) or b) if your array is so large that the function becomes slow indeed. Than again, have a look if you really need to rotate the array or if you can adjust your code to not require a 90°-rotated matrix

Comment: yes my array is very large, eg: 1000x1000x100 and therefore it is very  slow. Okay I`m going to investigate whether I need it. Thanks guys

Comment: @Chief define very slow. But yes, operations on large dataset take long. That is how computers work....